# Why does a ball rotate sometimes when you throw it?

Tags: torque, angular-velocity

My guess is that when you throw a ball, which is held by your hand, using you arm, the radius of the circular path being constant, the outermost part of the ball has a bigger radius than the innermost part, therefore greater linear acceleration for the outermost part of the ball. And so when you release it, the outermost part is always ahead in the direction of rotation than the innermost part.
[image]

Comment: i think it is because we also apply the force on the radial part of the ball.

Comment: @manshu, can you be more detailed?

Comment: if we apply the force such that the direction of force is passing through the center of ball then the ball will not rotate. But if we apply the force in other way then the ball will have torque due to which it will rotate.

Comment: @manshu, the reason I thought was that different parts of the ball have different tangential acceleration, not linear acceleration because for that we also have to take into consideration centripetal acceleration.

Comment: https://www.quora.com/Why-does-a-ball-thrown-up-in-the-air-always-rotate-while-falling-down have a look at this...

Answer (score 1):

Because your arm is effectively rotating, along with the ball, the latter will continue to rotate at the same speed after it leaves the hand. In reality, the fingers usually impart a spin though friction as the ball is released and slides out of the hand.

Comment: Is it then true that different parts of the ball has different tangential acceleration？

Comment: @Doeser tangential to what? And is the ball effectively rigid?

Comment: To the path of the circular path of the ball when you accelerate it

Comment: At high school level, everything is rigid (except ropes)